# ssh, heredoc and environment variables

Tags: shell-script, here-document

(This is RHEL 8.4, if it matters.)

The `echo` commands on lines 5 and 7 in this script run on the local host, but the `hostname` commands on lines 6 and 8 run on the remote host as expected.

Why do lines 5 and 7 run on the local host?  More importantly, **how do I get them to run on the remote host?**

EDIT: I **do not want** to **pass in** variables.  I want the variables to be solely defined and used on the remote server.

```
 1 #!/bin/bash
 2 export foo=bar
 3 ssh -q ${1} <<EOF
 4     export foo=blarge
 5     echo $foo
 6     hostname
 7     echo $foo
 8     hostname
 9 EOF
10 hostname
```

Comment: @ilkkachu **NO** because I **do not want** to pass variables, and do not think that my question indicates such a desire.  If it does, please indicate how.

Comment: did you even read the answer there? _"If you leave the heredoc keyword (i.e. EOF) unquoted then the heredoc body is processed locally, so that $FOO is expanded... "_ and _"If you quote the heredoc keyword then variable expansion is suppressed_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use quoted EOF:

```
$ ssh -q localhost <<'EOF'
export foo=blarge
echo $foo
EOF
blarge
```

You didn't specify what shell you use but in `man bash`
for example it says:

> If any part of word is quoted, the delimiter is the result of quote
> removal on word, and the lines in the here-document are not expanded.